# Simple recursive function is not working

Tags: php, function, recursion, scope

I'm trying to run a recursive function, but it doesn't work properly. I don't see any errors in my code, so maybe this is just not possible with PHP?

```
<?php

$herpNum = 0;

function herp() {
    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp();
    }
}

herp();

?>
```

when I run this, the result is just a long list of 1.

Comment: PHP doesn't have scope chains that work like JavaScript.

Comment: http://php.net/functions.user-defined - on that page see [*Example #4 Recursive functions*](http://php.net/functions.user-defined#example-150) for a similar but working variant.

Comment: Also please use the search before asking a question. I'm pretty sure QA material of how to write a recursive function in PHP exists on site already (next to the PHP manual itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $herpNum isn't in the same scope as the function, so it's creating a new $herpNum inside the function which defaults to 0 and then is adding 1 to it.

You could either pass it in as an arguement or have it as a global variable.

```
$herpNum = 0;

function herp($herpNum) {
    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp($herpNum);
    }
}

herp($herpNum);
```

or

```
$herpNum = 0;

function herp() {
    global $herpNum;

    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp();
    }
}

herp();
```

Comment: blasted, I forgot about having to define a variable as global. I haven't made a PHP function in a while :P

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII However, you should really avoid using globals. Use the version with function parameter instead.

Comment: what's wrong with globals? The only other answer I got for that didn't make any sense.

Comment: Using global variables pollutes the global namespace and may cause collisions in the future. Another reason is that global's are harder to test since it is usually more work if not impossible to use a mock or dummy for the global.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're not passing in the parameter `$herpnum` into the function.

```
<?php

$herpNum = 0;

function herp($herpNum) {
    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp($herpNum);
    }
}

herp($herpNum);

?>
```

That should work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `$herpNum` is redefinded as a local var in the scope of `herp()` each time `herp()` is called. This will lead to a recursion loop until an 'Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached ...'  error is thrown. (You can see the errors when you set the php ini value 'display_errors' to 'On')

Change the code above to :

```
$herpNum = 0;

function herp() {
    global $herpNum;
    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp();
    }   
}

herp();
```

Note that if `$herpNum` is only used by `herp()` it might be better to declare it as a static variable inside of `herp()`.

```
function herp() {
    static $herpNum = 0;
    // ...
```

The static keyword tells the PHP interpreter it should initialize the variable only once when the function is called the first time. This should perfectly fit your design needs ;)

Comment: Both suggestions are wrong, for recursion in PHP pass as parameter.

Comment: You are defeating the character of the recursiveness of the function. Each function invocation should have its own state. Static and global are single state, so there is a single state for *all* invocations, not a state per each invocation.

Comment: @hakre, @dualed The `global` 'suggestion' was just a correction of the code of the questioner, intended to answer his question. I would not use global variables in an recursive function, yes. But this was not the question. About the static approach one may think different, however the php manual at least [mentioned](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) it.

Comment: @hakre However, the best solution on the problem - printing the numbers from 0 to 22 to screen - would be iteration, isn't? ;)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$herpNum = 0;

function herp() {
    global $herpNum;
    if ($herpNum == 22) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $herpNum = $herpNum+1;
        echo $herpNum."<br/>";
        herp();
    }
}
herp();
```

But this is not recommended for security reasons.

Here is an example:

```
...
if( $admin == true ) {
  echo 'yeah! You are the admin!';
}
...
```

if `$admin` was declared as global and not verified properly, you just need to type `http://mysite.com/?admin=true` to make the test pass.

By the way... For a recursion, it's preferable to inject "environment" (one or more arguments) as parameter:

```
herp($herpNum=0); // if nothing is given, $herpNum is set to 0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on these security reasons? I see no issue with global variables.

Comment: but that would only apply if $admin were set via $admin = $_GET['admin'];, wouldn't it?

Comment: if you do `$admin=$_GET['admin']`, then later in your function calls you have got this: `function doSomething($admin=false) {...}` called with `doSomething()` without having `unset($admin)`, `$admin` will be considered as "true". By the way, I'm sure that you can find some configurations where `$admin` will be set if `$_GET['admin']` is provided.

Comment: What he is talking about is register_globals, which is off by default. If you turn it on, then if $_GET['admin'] is avaiable, then so will $admin and they will be ===.

Comment: Yes @Supericy. But `global $admin=$_GET['admin']` doesn't need register_global to be unsafe.